# how to get sum in jtable colmn

Tags: java, swing, parsing, integer

I'm trying to build my app and I need to get the sum of my `jtable` 5th column value, I used this code:

```
 public int getsum(){

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<jTable2.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
    }
    txt_Total_amount.setText(Integer.toString(sum));  
    return 0;
}
```

Then I have a runtime error:
//

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 2760"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at bankapplication.Register_customer.getsum(Register_customer.java:71)
at bankapplication.Register_customer.jButton5ActionPerformed(Register_customer.java:775)
at bankapplication.Register_customer.access$800(Register_customer.java:24)
at bankapplication.Register_customer$9.actionPerformed(Register_customer.java:488)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at bankapplication.MainInterface.jButton6ActionPerformed(MainInterface.java:569)
at bankapplication.MainInterface.access$700(MainInterface.java:25)
at bankapplication.MainInterface$7.actionPerformed(MainInterface.java:203)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I tried to change:

```
public int getsum(){

     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<jTable2.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
    }
    txt_Total_amount.setText(Integer.toString(sum));  
    return 0;
}
```

But will get the sum of the value in my 4th column, I need the sum of 5th column.

Comment: You _might_ want to reformat your question a bit to remove that huge stacktrace wall. Thus the question won't repell people who might be able to answer.

Comment: Additionally, have a look at the exception message: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 2760"` - now read the JavaDoc on `Integer.parseInt()` and you should be able to see the problem. (Hint: space)

Comment: Could you please Show us the getValueAt() method of your table model? There seems to be a leading or trailing space.

Comment: Plz tell me what is the wrong code and get me some example for do that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the message in the error is a good hint:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 2760" at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forIn

the issue is: `" 2760"` is not a string candidate that can be parsed into an integer(note the leading space)

so instead of

```
sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
```

do [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) that string

```
sum += Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 4).toString().trim());
```

Comment: Oh! thank you so much to helps to me your enplane is better to fix my issue Thanks again lot....:)